# Set the FontFamily of a RichEditBox from code behind in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a RichEditBox that I want to change the FontFamily of dynamically

I've tested that setting the FontFamily in XAML works as the line below changes the font correctly to `Consolas`:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="MainDocument" Width="750" Height="1500" Margin="0,175,0,25" Loaded="MainDocument_Loaded" FontFamily="Consolas">
```

However, I want to be able to set the font inside C# as opposed to XAML in order to dynamically update the box when I want. I've tried the following line:

```
MainDocument.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
```

But the font always defaults back to `Segoe UI`.

How can I set the font in code behind in UWP?

Comment: By my test, there's no problem when setting `FontFamily` in code. What's your project's target and min version? And what's your OS build version?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set this font inside the update data method end.

```
MainDocument.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
```